# How can I close this element after being shown for 5 seconds, every 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fake sales notification which shows a new popup every 20 seconds, the problem is, the notification is shown the whole 20 seconds until a new one shows up which also stays visible 20 seconds.

I need them to only be shown 5 seconds (but still show a new notification after 20 seconds). How can I do that?

This is my current jquery code:

```
setInterval(function(){
  random = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ) ;
  tpj(".custom-social-proof").hide('slow');
  tpj(".custom-social-proof").eq(random).stop().slideToggle('slow');
}, 20000);
```

I tried adding another interval for the `.hide` function like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  random = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ) ;
  tpj(".custom-social-proof").eq(random).stop().slideToggle('slow');
  setInterval(function(){
    tpj(".custom-social-proof").hide('slow');
  }, 5000);
}, 20000);
```

But the weird thing is this works the first time, but after another 20 seconds every popup dissapears in less than a second, not 5 seconds. Why is that?

Comment: Try using setTimeout instead of setinterval for hiding the notification

Comment: you are using `tpj(".custom-social-proof").eq(random)` to show popup and same is not the case while hide popup. what is the role of `random` here?

Comment: Your hide will start happening every 5 seconds forever... and in fact you are creating new hide intervals everytime the outer interval runs.. and none of them ever stop

Comment: You're using `setInterval` to hide, which means the code runs every 5 seconds. In addition, you keep creating a new 5-second interval every 20 seconds. Use `setTimeout` to hide instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used setInterval for hiding the popup which means you are calling that function every 5 seconds so it will clash with 20second interval. Use `setTimeout` instead

```
setInterval(function(){
  random = Math.floor( Math.random() * len ) ;
  tpj(".custom-social-proof").eq(random).stop().slideToggle('slow');
  setTimeout(function(){
    tpj(".custom-social-proof").hide('slow');
  }, 5000);
}, 20000);
```

Comment: No need for a `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using another `setInterval`, you should pass a callback as a second argument to `.hide` or `.show` to help detect when the animation is complete so you can show/hide.

Here is a close enough example to your code since there are some missing parts necessary to make your code work completely.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p class="custom-social-proof" style="display:none">
    Purchase Alert
  </p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
setInterval(function(){
  $(".custom-social-proof").show(2000, function() {
      $(".custom-social-proof").slideToggle(3000);
  });
}, 20000);
```

You can read on jQuery api documentation. [JQuery hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/)